# Who is this in the X-Men Apocalypse trailer?

Tags: marvel, x-men, character-identification, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse

In the very first seconds of the trailer in which Jean is dreaming you can see this frame:

[image: Jean Grey dream]

I may be thinking too much...but from what this looks like, its a feminine body... am I being paranoid or something? Isn't this suppose to be the Apocalypse?

Comment: Speculation - the shape reminds me of Nimrod a bit - but yeah, some feminine attributes there too so not likely 

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a7/Nimrodxmen.PNG?

Comment: @Keen :) Good comment! That's like saying we'll get there when we will get there! Or if someone is asking you the distance between here an the sun...you say no one has ever gone the distance...while if you had the knowledge needed you could have been able to answer... I was hoping if the body resembles any character or something of the comic books related to the story of Apocalypse...perhaps if you leave it open for a while so that we hear some opinions and then if you saw it as something that was opinion based then you would close it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's Jean.  Bryan Singer [says](http://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/x-men-apocalypse-trailer-breakdown/):

> The trailer opens with what we took to be a shot of Apocalypse walking menacingly through Cerebro, the device that James McAvoy’s Professor X uses to pinpoint hot mutant singles in his area. Not so, according to Singer.
>
> “That’s actually Jean,” he says, referring to Sophie Turner as a young version of Jean Grey, the powerful telekinetic who we last saw played by Famke Janssen in X-Men: The Last Stand. “Her hair makes her a little strange looking! But I don’t want to explain why she’s doing what she’s doing…”